# How i can remove Windows 7 Sound Schemes?

Tags: windows-7

I've tried to delete the sounds Cityscape,vCharacters, etc. But it did not work.

Is there a way to delete the files in this image?

[image]

Comment: I haven't tried removing win7 sound schemes, but generally if your issue is you can't delete a file.. then you can try a program called unlocker, and if all else fails, then you could always boot up a live OS CD, Win PE, or Bart PE or a linux, and delete it no problem. And you can look up the problem of not being able to delete a file. Your question may come under that category.

Comment: For those folders, perhaps change ownership to yourself amd grant full control permissions to see if you cam delete the files.